# Node http-proxy not working behind proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy

I am using the [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) module, which is an express middleware. the middleware module relies on [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). The node host is running behind a proxy.
I want to forward certain routes to a different service (for test purposes let's assume httpbin.org). So I defined the proxy as follows.

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var aeProxy = proxy({
    target: 'http://httpbin.org',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/ae':'/get'
    }
});
app.use('/api/ae', proxy);
```

I have also set the respective env variables (from debugging console):

```
process.env.HTTP_PROXY
> "http://proxy:8080"
process.env.HTTPS_PROXY
> "http://proxy:8080"
```

Unfortunately I only get timeouts. When running the node script in an environment without a proxy it works as expected.

Is my configuration wrong?

Comment: You have to set the ENV variables http_proxy = 'http://proxy.example.com:3129';

Comment: sorry, forgot toadd that I have set those env variables. Making a request (using request module) to the same URL even works correctly.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to [chimurai](https://github.com/chimurai) for [this](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/corporate-proxy.md) on how to connect via a corporate proxy via the ***agent*** field.

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

// corporate proxy to connect to via environment variables
var proxyServer = process.env.HTTPS_PROXY ||
                  process.env.HTTP_PROXY;

var options = {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',//Proxy url
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer)//The actual corporate proxy sever 
};

var apiProxy = proxy('/api', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a V2Ray protocol, you can just set the listening address and port of your connection like bellow and you'r good to go.

```js
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
const { createProxyMiddleware, fixRequestBody } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      logLevel: "debug",
      onProxyReq: fixRequestBody,
      agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://127.0.0.1:1087'),
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN
      },
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': ''
      }
    })
  );
};
```